# Difference between Foreground service vs Activity in android

Tags: android, optimization, service, foreground-service

I am trying to create one hobby app on Android rooted device. In this app there is no need for user interaction as well and app need to run continuously . I am trying to use some sensors (accelerometer/gps) and camera also.
I have 2 approaches for this implementation as mentioned below-

**1- Single Activity with Kiosk mode**

**2- Foreground Activity starting from application class**

So I am looking for pros and cons for both the approaches in terms for battery , some background tasks etc.

Does doze mode/screen sleep impact activity and foreground service differently?

---

**Edit-1**

I am using custom ROM for my embedded project . I need to keep it for single application and user interaction is not there. I was thinking for better approach for my project in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking about creating an app that runs some sort of task without an active user. In this case, you're looking into [deferred and exact tasks](https://developer.android.com/guide/background#deferred).

You can use [`WorkManager`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to schedule tasks to be executed at the exact time.

As for the services, there is a distinction between foreground and background ones. Please note that Android opposes certain [background execution restrictions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) when you're targeting SDK versions 26 and above. With [foreground services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#start), you're required to display a status bar notification.

The documentation clearly states that the use of `WorkManager` is preferred over starting a foreground service. I would advise you to read [this Medium article](https://medium.com/kayvan-kaseb/using-android-workmanager-8781559b5a1d) for more information.

Comment: I am using custom rom for my embedded project . I need to keep it for single application and user interaction is not there. I was thinking for better approach for my project in that case.